# SQL command for update in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I've been having a lot of trouble with these simple lines of code. I tried fixing it many times, but I don't seem to get it. I hope someone can help me with this.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE dbo.Status SET Status = "<span class=\"label label-success\">Success</span>" WHERE ActivateMember = " +i + "", 
                                mydatabase.cn);
```

The problem is I'm unable to execute that `SqlCommand` in C# but I'm able to execute it as a SQL query.

Right now the error is

> Unexpected character '\'

Comment: You need to surround the value with single quotes: `"'<span class=\"label label-success\">Success</span>'"` but you should really use parameterized queries instead to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: SqlCommand usually indicates MS SQL Server, not MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to use Parameters, it will save you a lot of trouble.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE dbo.Status SET Status = @status WHERE ActivateMember = @activateMember",mydatabase.cn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("status", "<span class=\"label label-success\">Success</span>");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("activateMember", i);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm sorry as I'm still new in coding.

Comment: @CedeeCQ If this answer works for you, don't forget to Accept it as the answer

Comment: @JayV Mandatory read: https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: And it's also worth noting that `SqlCommand` is `IDisposable`, so should be in a `using` block. And unless I'm mistaken, the first parameter to AddWithValue is the name of the parameter, so it should start with an @ ([example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)); but agree it's better not to use AddWithValue anyway, as mentioned above.

Comment: @Richardissimo Totally agree with the `using` block, always a good idea to use a using block if you can. For the Parameter Name though, when adding the parameter it's not necessary to add the '@' prefix. That is only necessary for the parameter name in the Sql statement (or `:` for Oracle statements)